# SonarQube and DotCover issue

Tags: sonarqube, dotcover

I am importing DotCover results into SonarQube and I am seeing differences in the coverage percentages that are being reported in Sonar compared to the percentages that I can see in the raw DotCover html.

At the individual class level, this looks like it is related to the way that Sonar is calculating the number of coverable statements. This looks much different to what I am seeing in the DotCover html and the result is that different percentages are showing via the SonarQube dashboard.

Is this a known issue or is there a way to ensure that the percentages get imported into Sonar correctly?

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube does the aggregating of code coverage itself, and imports only the file level coverage information from the dotCover report.

The overall code coverage information on the project level might differ if dotCover considers the project to include N files, but SonarQube sees M files for example.

SonarQube doesn't compute what is a "coverable" statement, it uses the file level information provided by dotCover: Each line that has code coverage information (i.e. that has hits > 0 or == 0) is considered to be coverable. Feel free to post a follow-up question if you see differences on a single file between what dotCover reports and what SonarQube reports.